# SQL Server trigger(s) to maintain one IsPrimary/IsDefault row per FK

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, database-trigger

We have a few tables with an `IsPrimary` column, e.g. many members belonging to an account. The requirement is if an account has one or more members, one and only one of them must have `IsPrimary = 1`. We want to achieve this using triggers for both maximum assurance of data integrity and ease of use from applications. But due to the batch nature of triggers, I'm struggling to accomplish it and in the most efficient way.

So far I have an `insert`/`delete` trigger (see below) that handles inserting a new primary record or deleting the primary record. Where I got stuck is ensuring the first record inserted has `IsPrimary=1` and then realizing there could be multiple modifications to the same account in the batch...

Does anyone have any experience or and example with something like this?

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.trg_PrimaryTest_InsertDelete 
   ON  dbo.PrimaryTest 
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    --SET NOCOUNT ON;
    PRINT 'executing trigger'

        --If inserting a primary, set all others to 0
        UPDATE      PrimaryTest 
        SET         IsPrimary = 0
        FROM        inserted
        INNER JOIN  PrimaryTest ON inserted.fk_ID = PrimaryTest.fk_ID
        WHERE       inserted.IsPrimary = 1 
                    AND PrimaryTest.pk_ID <> inserted.pk_ID
                    AND PrimaryTest.IsPrimary = 1

        --If deleting the primary, set most recent remaining phone to 1
        UPDATE      PrimaryTest
        SET         IsPrimary = 1
        WHERE       PrimaryTest.pk_ID IN (
                        SELECT TOP 1 PrimaryTest.pk_ID
                        FROM        deleted
                        INNER JOIN  PrimaryTest ON deleted.fk_ID = PrimaryTest.fk_ID
                        WHERE       deleted.IsPrimary = 1
                        ORDER BY    PrimaryTest.CreatedDate DESC
                    )

        PRINT 'trigger executed'
END
GO
```

Table ddl:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PrimaryTest](
    [pk_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [IsPrimary] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [fk_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PrimaryTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [pk_ID] ASC
)
GO
```

**EDIT:**

I think this might work or is at least headed in the right direction. I think it may be reading more records than it needs to in the 2nd C.T.E. case though. (Note I added `update`)

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.trg_PrimaryTest_InsertDelete 
   ON  dbo.PrimaryTest 
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    --SET NOCOUNT ON;
    PRINT 'executing trigger'

        --If setting a new primary, set all others to 0
        UPDATE      PrimaryTest 
        SET         IsPrimary = 0
        FROM        inserted
        INNER JOIN  PrimaryTest ON inserted.fk_ID = PrimaryTest.fk_ID
        WHERE       inserted.IsPrimary = 1 
                    AND PrimaryTest.pk_ID <> inserted.pk_ID
                    AND PrimaryTest.IsPrimary = 1

        --Set IsPrimary on any modified sets left without an primary 
        ;WITH cte
        AS
        (
            SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fk_ID ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) as RowNum 
            FROM    PrimaryTest p1
            WHERE   fk_ID IN (SELECT FK_ID FROM inserted UNION SELECT FK_ID FROM deleted)   --Only look at modified sets
                    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM PrimaryTest p2 WHERE p2.fk_ID = p1.fk_ID AND p2.IsPrimary = 1) --Select rows in a set without an IsPrimary=1 record
        )
        UPDATE cte
        SET IsPrimary = 1
        WHERE RowNum = 1

    PRINT 'trigger executed'
END
GO
```

Comment: Can you post the ddl for your table?

Comment: @SeanLange added.

Comment: To paraphrase: For every group of rows in `PrimaryTest` having a common value of `fk_ID` always force the most recent row, by `CreatedDate`, to have `IsPrimary` set to `1`. All other rows in the group must have `IsPrimary` set to `0`. In the event of a tie on `CreatedDate` use the row with the largest `pk_ID`. Does that accurately describe your goal? Is something stranger supposed to happen for `update` statements?

Comment: @HABO - Almost, except I explicitly insert or update a record with/to `IsPrimary=1`, it should be set to 1. The most recent record rule only comes into play if a group of rows is left without a record with `IsPrimary=1`.